# Design Pattern to follow for long running rest API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, message-queue, quarkus

I have a rest api which takes an input from user and executes a background task which runs for about 2-3 hours. User cannot make another call to this api till the first task completes.

So I am planning to use a queue to store the request as and when they come and not block the user.

Should I use java inbuilt collection for it or external queues like RabbitMQ?

Note : We are only going to store 3 messages in the queue and its not a distributed application.
Any other suggestions are also welcome

Comment: The approach is right and the implementation is entirely your choice. You have the option of doing everything yourself, but using a message broker + MDB will give you a good asynchronous implementation.

Comment: If these are processed in the background, I don't understand why you'd need to block the user.

Comment: Once you receive a request add it in a cache (NoSQL DBs are good choice) and return the accepted status to user, run a scheduler to pick pending requests from cache and run your job, don't run a new job if there are any job running at any point of time.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need a distributed queue if you wish to horizontally scale this service and if you want tasks to persist across reboots. What I would do is create 3 components: the backend application, the queue, and a database. Then the workflow will look something like this:

1. User submits task through REST API. Backend application queries database to check if a task for the current user is already running. If not, submit the task to the queue and record the new task status in the database.
2. Queue consumer picks up the task (the consumer can be the same application or a separate one). Consumer works on the task and updates database with task status (i.e. failed, running, at checkpoint 3, etc.).
3. Optionally, the client can query the task status through the REST API.
4. Task either completes successfully or fails. Exit status is persisted in database. Now there's no running task for the user, so the REST API will allow another submission per the logic in step 1. You can also do some things here like send an email, Slack notification, etc.

There may be some queue implementations that give you more freedom in querying task status, but I prefer this design since it offers a lot of flexibility and it's agnostic to the queue service used.

Answer (score 1):

Using an external queue would be a better choice:

1. Scalability and Performance: External message queues like RabbitMQ and Kafka are designed to handle large volumes of messages. They already deployed advanced techniques to optimize message delivery, such as batching, compression, and parallel processing.
2. Durability: External queues provide durable message storage, meaning messages are stored on disk and can survive server crashes or restarts. This ensures that messages are not lost in case of system failures or unexpected errors.
3. Decoupling: External queues provide a decoupling mechanism between the producer and consumer. This means that the REST API can produce messages to the queue without blocking, and the background task workers can consume messages from the queue at their own pace. This allows for better separation of concerns and reduces the risk of system failures due to bottlenecks or overloading.
4. Integration with other systems: External message queues like RabbitMQ and Kafka provide APIs and integration points with other systems and frameworks, such as Spring Boot, Django, Express.js, Golang, etc. which can simplify the development and deployment process.